# Split large amount of wav files to small parts

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav

I have large amount of wav files (over 50 000) and I need to split every wav file to 10 second long parts. It's nearly impossible to do it one by one, so my question is: is there any way to do it in ffmpeg or for example in sox? I'm an amateur, so I need exact instructions. Please, if you can, write it like you would for a dummy :)... (I'm a Windows 7 user)

[Here is my try with sox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdaUP.jpg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same task few days ago. I prefer to do it on Linux OS machines, but I had to do some demonstration on Windows machines so I have written this batch file using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html):

```
@ECHO OFF

rem Author: PetarF, 2017-07-01, v0.1
rem
rem Example of how to do batch processing with SoX on MS-Windows.
rem In this example, for every .wav file in folder the splited .wav file ends up in a folder called as original file without extension
rem In my case, this file has to be run as administrator
rem
rem USAGE: 
rem Place this file in the same folder as sox.exe (& rename it as appropriate).
rem Place .wav files that has to be splited in same folder as sox.exe

ECHO Split started
cd %~dp0
for %%A in (*.wav) do (
    mkdir %%~nA
    sox %%A %%~nA/%%~nA_.wav trim 0 10 : newfile : restart
    echo Created folder %%~nA with splited files
)
echo SoX has splited files...
pause
```